# Material-UI v5: makeStyles's not being imported

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I am trying to import "makeStyles" using :

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

it's not working. The page becomes blank when I run.

But It's working when I change the code and use V4:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

I've installed alll the dependencies that is required. Why It's not working using V5 of material-ui?

Here is my code (styles.js):

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material";

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
title: {
  display: "none",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    display: "block",
  },
},
}));
```

Header.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, InputBase, Box } from "@mui/material";

import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.title}>
          Travel Advsior
        </Typography>
        <Box display="flex">
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Explore new places
          </Typography>
          <div>
            <div>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase placeholder="Search..." />
          </div>
        </Box>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: what is the installed version as shown in your package.json?

Comment: Sounds like you are migrating MUI v4 to v5. You could check your `ThemeProvider` where it was imported from and read over this. https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4

Comment: The installed version of what @LironShirazi?

Comment: @SrayoshiGhosh Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.